# ChronicleQueue - how to read custom object from tailer

Tags: chronicle-queue

I am very new to ChronicleQueue and I am unable to find a straight forward example of how can I read back my custom object from a tailer.

```
public class MyData extends AbstractMarshallable
```

I have my class containing some strings and numbers, I am able to write to queue using appender, but there is no straight forward api to call.  how can i get a object of MyData from tailer.readDocument api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with below code:

```
final DocumentContext context = queue.createTailer().readingDocument();
final MyData container = new MyData();
if (context.isPresent()) {
    context.wire().getValueIn().marshallable(container);
}
```

this assumes that appending is performed in the following manner:

```
try (DocumentContext ctx = appender.writingDocument()) {
    ctx.wire().getValueOut().marshallable(myData);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Very close i guess, but i get this now, on this line "context.wire().getValueIn().marshallable(container);" 
 net.openhft.chronicle.core.io.IORuntimeException: Length unknown

Comment: btw, I am writing it like this:  appender.writeDocument(myData);

Comment: Sorry, do you have an example fragment of what you mean by symmetric?